# CSS suddenly not working ever since the next day

Tags: css

Ok so i have been trying to learn front end development and it was going fine, until the next day and suddenly all css stopped working, from my own projects on my chromebook and even on my personal pc which worked before, this happened about 1 month ago, and ever since when i try to do any type of css it just doesn't work.
It's not because of the browser, i tried chrome, opera gx and vivaldi and it just doesn't work.
This is just really frustrating and makes me want to go for back end since i can just work on the logic and stuff.
Did this also happen to anybody else and has a solution, please send it.
obs: i tried deleting cache and browser data and nothing.
The problem isn't with the code, i have tried to do so manyn different projects and in all of them the css doesn't work.
The problem isn't on my computer either because it's also not working on my chromebook which shouldn't happen, it feels like this problem is chasing me

Comment: We can only speculate since you present no CSS or details that we can assist you with here

Answer (score -1):

Without your code posted it's not too easy to answer this but here are a few steps to ensure your environment is set up okay.

First inside your `<html> </html>` insert a `<head>` with the appropriate reference to your stylesheet.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

The other way is by using inline styles on your HTML document directly.

```
<style>
   p {
     color: yellow;
   }
</style>
```

Without a more clear description or code examples it's a bit hard to give you an exact tutorial on what to do. This is just two ways you can set your stylesheet up as a new web developer.

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing the internet with your browser, if possible, to see if css of production sites will show.
If it does, then the issue may actually be from your code.
If it doesn't, then you may need to uninstall and install your browser(s).